# How to do if condition inside foreach in Makefile

Tags: makefile

In Makefile, the pupose is to find a match in a list

```
#to find the $VER_X which is latest to $MY_VERSION but not greater than $MY_VERSION
VER_1 := 50.0.56.8
VER_2 := 50.0.56.17
VER_3 := 50.0.90.0

#in this case, VER_2 should be the match one
MY_VERSION := 50.0.56.19
```

I write a function which works fine to compare version string such as a.b.c.d

```
# function - compare version such as a.b.c.d
version_greater_equal = $(shell if printf '%s\n%s\n' '$(2)' '$(1)' | sort -Ct. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n ; then echo YES; else echo NO; fi)
```

The pupose is to find a match which is latest to ${MY_VERSION}

**Solution-A and it works.**

```
#solution-A: enumerate via ifeq
#this works, but it is not good idea for a larget number of VER_X
ifeq (YES,$(call version_greater_equal,${MY_VERSION},${VER_1}))
MATCH_ENU=${VER_1}
endif
ifeq (YES,$(call version_greater_equal,${MY_VERSION},${VER_2}))
MATCH_ENU=${VER_2}
endif
ifeq (YES,$(call version_greater_equal,${MY_VERSION},${VER_3}))
MATCH_ENU=${VER_3}
endif
```

**Soluton-B , which doesn't work. How can I fix it?**

```
#solution-2: loop (foreach)
VER_LIST := 50.0.56.8  50.0.56.17  50.0.90.0  50.1.42.3
MATCH_2 := $(foreach each, $(VER_LIST), $(if $(call version_greater_equal,${MY_VERSION},${each})=YES , ${each}))
```

The log

```
-->enumerate
MATCH_ENU   = 50.0.56.17
-->enumerate
MATCH_2     =   50.0.56.8   50.0.56.17   50.0.90.0   50.1.42.3
```

Comment: You cannot use `=YES` in an if-statement.  Make if-statements don't have equality etc. operators; that's not how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new function, which returns the second argument if it's greater-or-equal, or nothing.

```
version_greater_equal = $(shell if printf '%s\n%s\n' '$(2)' '$(1)' | sort -Ct.   -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n ; then echo $(2); fi)
```

Make a (sorted) list of versions:

```
VERS := $(VER_1) $(VER_2) $(VER_3) ...
```

Sift out the one greater than `$(MY_VERSION)`:

```
LOW_VERS := $(foreach X,$(VERS),$(call version_greater_equal,${MY_VERSION},$(X)))
```

Take the last (and therefore greatest) of these:

```
MATCH_ENU := $(lastword $(LOW_VERS))
```

**EDIT:** Your Question seemed to imply that the versions would be listed in order (and your **Solution A** depends on it). But if you want a solution that works without that assumption, here goes.

I will not give a recursive function that returns just the largest value, because recursive functions give me vertigo. And besides, the advice @MadScientist gives me usually contains some horrible trap. So here's a purely iterative solution:

```
greater = ... function that returns the greater of the two arguments, you write it.

define reduce
X := $(call greater, $(wordlist 1,2,$(X))) $(wordlist 3,$(words $(X)), $(X))
endef

X := $(LOW_VERS)

$(foreach z, $(LOW_VERS), $(eval $(call reduce)))
```

Now `X` will contain the version you want.

**P.S.** Come to think of it, if we're making calls to the shell `sort`, it's probably easier just to sort the version list that way.

Comment: An alternative is to write a recursive function that can return just the largest value, regardless of whether the list is in sorted order.  But I leave that as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks Beta that the function works well.
Only I need to do is to get a sorted list. 
But $(sort $VERS) seems didn't work for  a.b.c.d , example, it will get 50.0.56.18 always head of  50.0.56.8. Still searching on how to sort these $VERS.

Comment: Thanks MadScientist,  a recursive function, very good idea. 
But I'm not familir with Make function or shell function ... so it's still difficult for me ... 
Thanks anyway. That's a great idea.